# Unable to print Cosecant/Secant values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am unable to execute these math functions in Xcode: `secant(sec) / cosecant(cosec)`

```
NSLog(@"cosec(45)=%f",cosec(45 * M_PI/180.0));
```

**Error:**

> Showing cot/sec/cosec are implicit declaration of function cot/cosec is invalid in c99

Is there a way I can run these math functions?

**Note**
I am only able to run tan/sin/cos functions

Comment: `sin`/`cos` are defined in `math.h`, but I don't know if `cot`/`sec`/`cosec` are even defined, and where. If they are, you need to do the correct `#import "headerWhereTheyAreDefined.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this error because 'cosec' function is not implemented in libraries you are compiling with. Try to replace usage of this function with trigonometrically equivalent operations like `secant(x) = 1.0 / cos(x)` and `cosecant(x) = 1.0 / sin(x)`.

Comment: Thanks for help . It worked NSLog(@"Cosec(30)=%f",1/sin(30 * M_PI/180.0));

Comment: be careful with integer literals (and variables) in your equations when you expect float result. `NSLog(@"Cosec(30)=%f",1.0/sin(30.0 * M_PI/180.0));`